# Data export: Views vs Tracking Extract

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views, data-extract, tracking-extract

If we have to make a choice at this moment, on which process we are going to use to extract daily campaign data from SFMC to an external data warehouse, what would be the best (future proof) solution.

- Exporting the views using activities (in an automation)
- Tracking Extract

If i'm correct, Tracking Extract does not contain journey builder data. Where in the system views you have the _JourneyActivity and _Journey views.

From that perspective, I think the views are the best choice. Especially now that you see that Salesforce is increasingly focusing on Journey Builder.

What is your opinion on this?

Comment: The data views are limited to 6 months of data and are problematic in terms of performance at scale.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs  If the six months is not an issue, for example a new installation where you want to create a daily export to a data warehouse for all data of the last 24h. I tend to go with the data views, because it looks like journey builder data seems better supported here. In Tracking Extract for example, it seems not possible to retrieve mails from (specific versions of) journeys based on journeyID. Also EmailID seems not available.  So for reporting  purposes, the views seem like the best choice. From a data perspective, I see no benefits for using Tracking. But maybe i'm missing something

Comment: What specifically are you gaining from the Journey data views?  Some non-email interaction or version metadata?  Journey sends are just triggers that are included in the tracking extracts.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs  For example, I have a journey, with multiple versions, using emails that are also being used in other journey's. If I want to retrieve the results of a specific email in a specific version using the views, I can use journeyname or journeyID to retrieve the versionID and the attached emails.
In Tracking data there is no journeyname, journeyID, or versionid. How would you look up the data for a specific mail in a specific version there?

Comment: So reporting on sends/opens/clicks to journey _versions_ is relevant to your reporting requirements?  I would never recommend building any reporting based on the data views if you have a large send volume -- that is unless you like troubleshooting query timeout errors.  Reporting is best done in a data warehouse using tracking extract data.  If it has to be done in SFMC, then dump tracking extract data out and import it back into data extensions with short retention periods.

Comment: Reading the docs, I think the TriggeredSendExternalKey field in TEs might be the link between events and journeys. Interested to hear if someone can verify.